# Android bug? Popup dialogs and spinners invisible; screen dims

Tags: android, opengl, spinner

I have an app that has a few Spinners and a couple of Buttons that pop up Dialogs.  Other Buttons start new Activities.

On startup, these all work fine.  However, when a new Activity is started and then we return, *all* pop-up elements stop working properly - the screen dims, but no dialog appears.  In this state:

- if you tap where the dialog's buttons *should* be (such as an "OK" button), their callbacks are called and everything works fine
- rotating the phone will cause a redraw and the dialog will be visible again

This seems to me to be an Android bug.  There seem to be very few references to it anywhere, and I'm at a loss as to what triggers it, and how I can work around it.  As requested by @ethan, code fragment for one possible path is below, but there's little to it; I don't need to return any results, and the problem is exhibited when the user simply presses the Back button (which just has the default binding).

```
private OnClickListener button_click = new OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int lId = v.getId();
        ...
        if ( lId == R.id.cancel_button ) {
            finish();
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

This is probably not helpful - I'm hoping someone will recognize the symptom.  In the meantime, I'm trying to work up a mock example that exhibits the problem.

It does not occur in 1.5 or 1.6, but does in 2.2.

Comment: Can you post the snippet of code you use to return from your new Activity back to the original Activity?

Comment: Thanks very much for responding @ethan - additional detail added, but I'm not sure it's relevant.  I've narrowed it down further - the bug seems to be related, quite unexpectedly, to the presence of a GLSurfaceView in the calling Activity.  On removing this component, the symptom went away.  Will post a minimal representative case once I've worked one up.

Comment: I'm seeing the same error on my app, can't pinpoint it either, it just sometimes happens and then it doesn't stop happening for all error dialogs in the application.
I get the following lines in the log when a dialog is *not* showing up:
I/WindowManager(199): createSurface Window{***}: DRAW NOW PENDING
 V/PhoneStatusBar(271): setLightsOn(true)
W/InputManagerService(199): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41fceea8
V/PhoneStatusBar(271): setLightsOn(true)
I hope this helps... (running ICS on Galaxy Nexus)

Comment: @garethw, do you use opengl in your app? we do so it might be related...